# How to get all username of the members with discord.js 12.5.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

How I can get all usernames of the members from the guild with discord.js 12.5.3.

Here my code, but it not work:

```js
const { Client } = require('discord.js');
const client = new Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.guilds
    .fetch('827227617970749481')
    .then(guild => {
        guild.members
            .fetch()
            .then(member => console.log(member));
    });

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: Hi, I've just noticed that you unaccepted my answer after six weeks and accepted the other one instead. May I know what's the reason? Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this to get all members in the cache:

```js
const members = client.guilds.get("827227617970749481"); 
members.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));
```

Use this if you want every single member:

```
const members = client.guilds.get("827227617970749481"); 
members.members.fetch().then(members => console.log(members))
```

PS: It's not a good idea to post your Token in public ;)

Comment: Yes, I totally forgot about the token

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because when you're trying to fetch the `guild`, the bot is not yet logged in. You need to move that part to an event handler, like `.once('ready')`.

The following should work. First, [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildManager?scrollTo=fetch) the guild, then [`.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch) all the members and for each member log the [`username`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) property of the [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=user):

```js
const client = new Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
  console.log('Ready!');

  client.guilds.fetch('827227617970749481').then((guild) => {
    guild.members.fetch().then((members) => {
      members.each((member) => console.log(member.user.username));
    });
  });
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

You could also use async/await to make it more readable:

```js
const client = new Client();

client.once('ready', async () => {
  console.log('Ready!');

  const guild = await client.guilds.fetch('827227617970749481');
  const members = await guild.members.fetch();

  members.each((member) => console.log(member.user.username));
});

client.login(TOKEN);
```

Comment: I solve this yesterday by trigger the event with message command '!memberList' this make sure that the bot logged in

Comment: Yes, `client.on('message')` is also good ;) The idea is that it needs to be inside a handler.